# Access elements in a list in Rcpparmadillo?

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo

I am working with Rcpparmadillo and get an question about how to reach the elements in list.

It is understandable to do that when I return the values to R, now I want to know how to do that in c++, in other words, the list generated from a function is still be referred in c++.

For example, I have a function:

```
    List foo(...){
         .....
         return List::create(Named("example1") = example1, Named("example2") = example2)
    }
```

Now I have another function in C++ and `example1` is a variable in the function, so how to reach `example1` in C++.

Thanks in advance. I am not familiar with C++.

Answer (score 0):

I realised the return value is a list now and can be convert by `Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(...)`, '...' can be filled by the name of the list and the elements you want to reach, total the same stuff in R. Thanks for the help from @DirkEddelbuettel.

Comment: Wrong. How about reading the Rcpp documentation, now that you're using Rcpp?   `List` is `Rcpp::List` so ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I am using Rcpparmadillo, I build the List as I showed in my example. Now when I try to read the element in the list, I tried `REAL(VECTOR_ELT(x, 0))[0];` and it works well. But another quiz left is that if a vector or matrix is stored in the list, then how can I reach them as whole, by the method I presented, I can only reach the first element. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read *any* of our documentation?  Vignettes? [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org)?  What you used may "work" but is the basic C mode.  You can do much, much better ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I did not realise the data type is list in R even I did not call the function in R, I changed the solution now. Thanks indeed, I will be more prudent next time before i post the quiz here.